# Java - Trying to pass both no value and boolean, but returns null

Tags: java

Trying to pass no value and a boolean value of true over two different objects set for the same class.

According to the TestDriver:
The following should pass true as boolean via `public Iron(boolean val)`

```
Metal m1 = new Iron(true);
System.out.println("Should be Iron->"+m1);
System.out.println("Should be Enchanted (True)->"+m1.isEnchanted());`
```

However, passes as null, as though it is not reaching this constructor.
Tell me it's not trying to look at the Metal class instead with a constructor for Iron?

The second piece of code submits no value, but also returns null.
I have tried using `Boolean.parseBoolean()` in order to try and convert a string to boolean and vice versa.

I have tried a pelthora of different ways to get it to work, however cannot see to get anywhere, if I am missing something obvious, please do tell.

Cheers.

```
public class TestDriver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Metal m1 = new Iron(true);
        System.out.println("Should be Iron->"+m1);
        System.out.println("Should be Enchanted (True)->"+m1.isEnchanted());
        Iron i1 = new Iron();
        System.out.println("Should not be Enchanted (False)->"+i1.isEnchanted());
    }

}

public class Iron extends Metal {

    public boolean isEnchanted(boolean val) {       

        boolean res = false;

        if(val == true) {
            res = true;
        } else {
            res = false;
        }
        return (res);

    }

    public Iron() {

    }

    public Iron(boolean val) {

        boolean res = false;

        if(val == true) {
            res = true;
        } else {
            res = false;
        }
        //return (res);

    }
}
```

Expected true when passing true value and expecting false when passing no value, however when calling isEnchanted - should be called somehow.

Comment: Since `Iron#isEnchanted(boolean)` takes a parameter `m1.isEnchanted()` will call  `Metal#isEnchanted()` (assuming this method exists). This is called an overload and not an override, i.e. 2 methods with the same name but different parameters.

Comment: can we have a look at metal class also? Cause the problem seems to be the primitive

Comment: Btw, that `Iron(boolean)` constructor effectively doesn't do anything: it locally declares `res` which it not used at all. Aside from that, `if(val == true)` is the same as `if(val)` (and since you're only assigning `res` the entire method body could be replaced by `boolean res = val;` - which still wouldn't make much sense though).

Comment: I agree with @Thomas about the contructor as the parameter is never saved in the class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not included your `Metal` class, but I will put a working example of what you specified here to get you started.

Below is the `Metal` class I made to meet the requirements you want:

```
public class Metal {

    private boolean res;
    private String name;

    public Metal() {
        this.res = false;
    }

    public Metal (boolean res, String name) {
        this.res = res;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public boolean isEnchanted() {
        return res;       
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;       
    }
}
```

I added a `name` class field to be used when you want to override `toString` since you want to print the name when the field is used in `System.out.println`.  `toString()` can still be modified to print whatever you want in addition to the name.

Also take note of the changes to `IsEnchanted()`.  This should be only a `return` of the class variable `res` so you can see what the value is set to, you should not put in logic that changes the `boolean` here.

Also you attempted to use many *local* variables which is not the correct way to take advantage of using an *Object*.  See how the variable `res` is on the `class` level now and you no longer need to pass it around since you will be able to access it whenever you want to after setting it from the constructor the first time.

Here is the `Iron` class now after the modifications to the `Metal` class.  Notice how little is needed to be done inside of `Iron` at this point.  Most of the logic I assumed was to be used by other `Metal`s as well, so you can now `extend` `Metal` easily and get functionality in, for example, a `Copper` now:

```
public class Iron extends Metal {

    public Iron() {
    }

    public Iron(boolean val) {
        super(val, "Iron");
    }
}
```

The most important thing to note here is the call to `super(val, "Iron")` which will pass the `res` parameter to the `super` class's constructor and define the name to be `"Iron"`.  The `super` class in this case is `Metal`.

Now you can use your test code and it works as expected:

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    Metal m1 = new Iron(true);
    System.out.println("Should be Iron->"+ m1);
    System.out.println("Should be Enchanted (True)->" + m1.isEnchanted());
    Metal i1 = new Iron();
    System.out.println("Should not be Enchanted (False)->"+i1.isEnchanted());
}
```

**Output:**

> Should be Iron->Iron
>
> Should be Enchanted (True)->true
>
> Should not be Enchanted (False)->false

Comment: A small suggestion as you put some effort in this answer Iron should define its own name and not take it as parameters :) Iron should not expect someone else to tell it that its iron but know it for itself! either way nice answer

Comment: @Michael Michailidis Yeah good point, I'll make a change to it.

Comment: I know I shouldn't leave a thanks, but thanks Nexevis, that was an awesome answer and I obtained the same result as you. Appreciate the time spent resolving this. Had not taken using super into account. Thanks also to everybody else that contributed.